# Java blocking me from running a local java applet

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a simple applet that I want to run locally yet java is blocking it.

The applet code is as such:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FollowMe extends JApplet
{
private int xCoord = 100, yCoord = 100;

/**
 * init method
 */

public void init()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
}

/**
 * paint method
 */

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // Call the base class paint method.
    super.paint(g);

    // Draw the string at the current mouse location.
    g.drawString("Hello", xCoord, yCoord);
}

/**
 * Private inner class that handles mouse
 * motion events.
 */

private class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener
{
    /**
     * mouseMoved method
     */

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Get the mouse pointer's X and Y coordinates.
        xCoord = e.getX();
        yCoord = e.getY();

        // Force the paint method to execute.
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Unused mouseDragged method
     */

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

And of course I reference the class file in my HTML file. 
I have gone to my JAVA security settings and added the following exception:

"file:///D:/Downloads/AppletsExamples%281%29/01%20-%20FollowMe%20Applet/FollowMe.html"

which as you can see is the path I open in firefox to access my Html file.
However, JAVA still blocks the applet. This is getting so frustrating and I couldn't find any help elsewhere.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @VinceEmigh No I didn't sign it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes it's my teacher specifying it. I will refer it to him once I'm done with the course!
I've found a solution on my own, I managed to run the applet using the appletviewer in CMD which is sufficient enough for my needs. Thank you for your replies.